# How to fix Django's "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" error?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was trying to create the sending-verification-code system for the whole afternoon. It's like this:
serilizer.py

```py
class RegisterationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, help_text=_("Enter a valid password"))
    repeated_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, help_text=_("Enter your password again"))
    

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        email = data["email"] 
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        if User.objects.filter(email=email, is_active=False).exists(): 
            if VerficationCode.objects.filter(user=user).values("expire_date")[0]['expire_date'] < utc.localize(datetime.now()):
                VerficationCode.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
                verification_code = give_code()
                VerficationCode.objects.create(user=user, code=verification_code)
                send_mail("Verification Code", f"your code is: {verification_code}", "nima@gmail.com", [email])
                return Response({"Message": "A verification code has been sent to your email"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)   
            elif VerficationCode.objects.filter(user=user).values("expire_date")[0]['expire_date'] >= utc.localize(datetime.now()):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Your verification code is still valid"))
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["email", "username", "name", "password", "repeated_password"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'help_text': _("Enter your email")},
            'username': {'help_text': _("Enter your username")},
            'name': {'help_text': _("Enter your name"), 'required': False, 'allow_blank': True},
        }

    
    def validate(self, data):
        print(User.objects.filter(email=data["email"], is_active=False))
        if data["password"] and data["repeated_password"] and data["password"] != data["repeated_password"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Password and repeated password must be the same"))
        if data["email"].strip() == data["username"].strip():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Email and username must be different")) 
        return data
```

This code is overriding the is_valid() method in the user registration serializer.
But when I send another response with the username and password of an account that is existed but it's not active and the first inner if in the to_interval... function should trigger but it's not worked and it returns ValueError at /api/authentication/register/
too many values to unpack (expected 2); what should I do now?
full traceback error:

```
ValueError at /api/authentication/register/
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/authentication/register/
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Exception Location: E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\serializer_helpers.py, line 18, in __init__
Python Executable:  E:\projects\Rug\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.1

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/authentication/register/

Django Version: 4.0.1
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\backend\users\views.py", line 42, in post
    return Response(data.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 566, in errors
    return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)
  File "E:\projects\Rug\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\serializer_helpers.py", line 18, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: ValueError at /api/authentication/register/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback from the error to your question

Comment: My post is updated at the moment; check it.